# Close will hide keyboard and not navigate back

Tags: mvvmcross, uwp

I use MVVM Cross in my UWP app. I noticed that if I call Close(this) in my ViewModel and the keyboard is open it will just close the keyboard instead of navigate back. I have to click another time to actually do the navigation. 
This behaviour reminds me of the back button of the phone, where first the keyboard is closed and then the navigation is made.

EDIT: this seems only to happen when it's a view who contains a user control. When all code is directly in the view it works without problem.

Is there a way to tell MVVM Cross to just do the navigation? Or do I first have to be sure that the KeyBoard is closed?